# Newest method to detect small screen

Tags: javascript, css, browser-feature-detection

While waiting for responsive design to find the way into a legacy web site, I would like to redirect a browser to a mobile version if the screen is smaller than 480px

Hunting around I came up with

```
var isSmall = window.matchMedia ? 
              window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 480px)") : 
              screen.width<=480;
```

**Question**

Is this acceptable in 2014 or is there a better/safer/newer method to do what I want without using useragent sniffing?

**References**

- [MDN Window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)
- [JavaScriptKit CSS media query matching in JavaScript using window.matchMedia()](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries4.shtml)
- [QuirksMode screen.width is useless](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/11/screenwidth_is.html) (hence the addition of matchMedia)

Comment: Make sure to check up on iPhone 4+ as they have a screen width of `640px` but report their screen width as `320px` for legacy reasons.

Comment: But since they support matchMedia as far as I understand does that not return false before using screen.width?

Comment: Fwiw, the slight advantage you have with user agent sniffing is that you can do this server side, resulting in a slightly faster experience because a redirect doesn't contain a document. You would probably still want a cookie based switch between mobile / desktop, though.

Comment: Seems still valid in 2023. Here is an article from 2020 https://webdevetc.com/blog/matchmedia-events-for-window-resizes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a polyfill such as https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Comment: I will have to think about this. Not sure if it is needed .

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ or
foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/
these two frameworks has a powerful multi device layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is lot of tricky ways :) to choose windows width but our Team's view you didn't have to include any tricks to know just windows.width because jQuery has a .width() function like:

```
var window_width = $(window).width();
if( window_width <= 480 ){
  console.log(window_width);
}
```

***Iphone 4S***, ***Iphone 5***, ***Iphone 5S*** Every one's **Screen Width** is **320px**. Your Mobile Resolution isn't your mobile's Screen Width. so when you include your tricks to know just windows width or something you just increase your Application's loadspeed this gonna be a problem for your user. But you know that was the designer's issue why they complicate the designs for developers & for End Users. :)